# AngularJS routing doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm currently building a small application. I want my URL's like this /index (without the .html). I tried to use NgRoute for that, but it doesn't seem to work out well. When i go to /establishments, it says the route doesn't exists. Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('khApp', ['ngRoute','establishmentModule', 'queryModule', 'buildingBlockModule', 'categoryModule']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider)
{
  $routeProvider
    .when('establishments', {controller:'testController', templateUrl: '../html/establishments.html'})

}]);

app.controller('testController', ['$http', function($http)
{


}]);
```

**index.html**

```
    <div  ng-controller="testController as test" class="container">
        hi 
        <a href="establishments">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Start</button>
        </a>
    </div>

  <ng-view></ng-view>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/buildingblock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/category.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/establishment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/query.js"></script> 


</body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What URL are you entering in the browser? Full URL please (though you can omit the actual host name)

Comment: @mason http://localhost:port/application/app/html/establishments

Comment: @henktenk I think you may misunderstand a bit about how angular is designed to work in general, and specifically how the angular router works.  If you would like, we can start a chat and I can give you some pointers, or you can find me most days in the general javascript chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your router is configured, typically you need to target routes beginning with a slash like so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('establishments', {
                controller:'testController',
                templateUrl: '../html/establishments.html'
            });
}]);
```

In addition, in your HTML, I think your HTML anchor tags need to begin with the hash navigation like so:

```
<a href="#/establishments">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Start</button>
</a>
```

**Reference:** [AngularJS Documentation Tutorial 7 - Routing & Multiple Views](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

Comment: This solution works, but it loads the establishment.html into the index.html. What i'm aiming for is that the route loads an entire new page, establishment.html in this case.

Comment: In that case, I think all you need to do then is have `establishments.html` in your anchor tag as your `href`. The router is meant to be used for the single page applications (spa) development style. In this case, when the page navigates, all previous JS processing will be lost. You'll need to include the relevant parts of your code on the `establishments.html` page as well. Using a router to navigate between two completely different pages will be pointless.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's too bad. But how would you accomplish nice URL's while navigating through different pages, such as company/establishments loading establishments.html?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an MVC style architecture pattern. Not completely sure though. Using the AngularJS router or something like [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) will allow for client hash based (or with HTML 5 history based) navigation to a sort of restful style url. SEO friendly urls like what you're describing executed from the server only usually occur by rewriting the url on the server to load a controller which in turn loads a model and view, thus utilizing the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS routing utilizes the fragment identifier (the `#` in the URL) to get its routes. That's because it can't manipulate the full URL without causing the browser to request a new page, thus making it not a SPA.

So the URL you need to request should be the form of `<path to root>#/establishments`. Assuming `index.html` is in `/application/app/html`, the URL to request would be:

```
/application/app/html/index.html#/establishments
```

If you *also* want to support the URL  `localhost:port/application/app/html/establishments` then you need to configure your server side routing to perform a redirect to `/application/app/html/index.html#/establishments`.

Answer (score 0):

#/establishments is what you need in your anchor tag

```
<a href="#/establishments">
<button class="btn btn-default">Start</button>
</a>
```

your route will be something like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('establishments', {
            controller:'testController',
            templateUrl: '../html/establishments.html'
        });
}]);
```